# What are the directories for each Android studio component?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, directory, components

I've installed **Android studio** lately, and tried to let it download the components by itself, but i got few errors while downloading them ..

**Please refer** that the product was not available for my current location, so i used a proxy to get the direct link, and then went back to my original IP and installed it successfully.

Then when the wizard started to download the components, it kept viewing an error downloading message for the components, so i also tried to use a proxy, but this time it didn't work (*same error downloading message*) so i got the direct links for each component from <sup>Show Details</sup>  option and installed few already successfully and got into the directory

> C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

to put them in their places, but i'm still confused about some directories

## So can you provide the directories for the following components:

- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform 28
- Android SDK Tools
- Google Repository
- Sources for Android 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the Android SDK directory structure.

```
sdk
    ├── SDK\ Readme.txt
    ├── add-ons
    │   ├── addon-google_apis-google-28
    │   └── addon-google_apis-google-8
    ├── build-tools
    │   └── 28.0.0
    ├── cmake
    │   ├── 3.6.3155560
    │   └── 3.6.4111459
    ├── emulator
    │   ├── NOTICE.txt
    │   ├── bin64
    │   ├── emulator
    │   ├── emulator-check
    │   ├── emulator64-arm
    │   ├── emulator64-crash-service
    │   ├── emulator64-mips
    │   ├── emulator64-x86
    │   ├── lib
    │   ├── lib64
    │   ├── mksdcard
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   ├── qemu
    │   ├── resources
    │   └── source.properties
    ├── extras
    │   ├── android
    │   ├── google
    │   ├── intel
    │   └── m2repository
    ├── fonts
    │   └── com.google.android.gms.fonts
    ├── licenses
    │   ├── android-sdk-license
    │   ├── android-sdk-preview-license
    │   └── intel-android-extra-license
    ├── lldb
    │   └── 3.1
    ├── ndk-bundle
    │   ├── CHANGELOG.md
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── build
    │   ├── meta
    │   ├── ndk-build
    │   ├── ndk-depends
    │   ├── ndk-gdb
    │   ├── ndk-stack
    │   ├── ndk-which
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   ├── platforms
    │   ├── prebuilt
    │   ├── python-packages
    │   ├── shader-tools
    │   ├── simpleperf
    │   ├── source.properties
    │   ├── sources
    │   ├── sysroot
    │   ├── toolchains
    │   └── wrap.sh
    ├── patcher
    │   └── v4
    ├── platform-tools
    │   ├── NOTICE.txt
    │   ├── adb
    │   ├── api
    │   ├── dmtracedump
    │   ├── e2fsdroid
    │   ├── etc1tool
    │   ├── fastboot
    │   ├── hprof-conv
    │   ├── lib
    │   ├── make_f2fs
    │   ├── mke2fs
    │   ├── mke2fs.conf
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   ├── sload_f2fs
    │   ├── source.properties
    │   ├── sqlite3
    │   └── systrace
    ├── platforms
    │   ├── android-28
    │   └── android-8
    ├── skins
    │   ├── AndroidWearRound
    │   ├── AndroidWearRoundChin320x290
    │   ├── AndroidWearSquare
    │   ├── galaxy_nexus
    │   ├── nexus_10
    │   ├── pixel_xl_silver
    │   ├── tv_1080p
    │   └── tv_720p
    ├── sources
    │   └── android-28
    ├── system-images
    │   └── android-28
    ├── temp
    └── tools
        ├── NOTICE.txt
        ├── android
        ├── bin
        ├── emulator
        ├── emulator-check
        ├── lib
        ├── mksdcard
        ├── monitor
        ├── package.xml
        ├── proguard
        ├── source.properties
        └── support
```

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for.. i have already made a check on some components' directories according to your feedback, and everything seems to be good, Thanks @shizhen !

Answer (score -1):

If you are facing with a proxy issue, maybe you should fix that proxy problem rather than manually manage your SDK directories. Refer to  https://arophix.com/2018/04/17/gradle-proxy-configuration/ for how to configure your proxy.